# Reading the contents of a live console

Tags: python, django, windows, console

I'm wondering if it's possible to read what's happening in Windows console live and either store it in a log/text file or store as a string of some sort as it runs.

Below is an example of some of the information that is displayed. In this case it's stating what is happening on a django/python webpage it is running:

```
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:50] "GET /color_liker/static/color_ajax_switch.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1697
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:52] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=th HTTP/1.1" 200 93
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:53] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=thi HTTP/1.1" 200 94
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:53] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this HTTP/1.1" 200 95
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:54] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this HTTP/1.1" 200 95
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:54] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this+i HTTP/1.1" 200 97
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:55] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this+is HTTP/1.1" 200 98
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:55] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this+is HTTP/1.1" 200 98
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:55] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this+is+a HTTP/1.1" 200 100
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:56] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this+is+a HTTP/1.1" 200 100
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:56] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this+is+a+t HTTP/1.1" 200 102
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:57] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this+is+a+te HTTP/1.1" 200 103
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:57] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this+is+a+tes HTTP/1.1" 200 104
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:58] "GET /color_liker/like_color_3/ HTTP/1.1" 200 46
[27/Feb/2016 14:51:59] "GET /color_liker/like_color_6/ HTTP/1.1" 200 45
[27/Feb/2016 14:52:00] "GET /color_liker/like_color_1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 45
[27/Feb/2016 14:52:01] "GET /color_liker/like_color_2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 45
[27/Feb/2016 14:52:03] "GET /color_liker/search/?color_search_text=this+is+a+test HTTP/1.1" 200 105
```

Basically, once able to read the file, I'd ideally be able to parse out the information I'm actually looking for, but I'm unsure of how to get to that stage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Are you getting all this information after you typed some command ?

Comment: It's possible to attach to a console and call [`ReadConsoleOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684965) to read the ouput buffer. But that's probably overkill for your needs.

Comment: I've had a look at that Redirect and I'm not sure if it applies to mine?
noob: Yes, I have entered the command now it is just running (it can no longer be edited)

Comment: Have you tried reading about powershell filters and pipes?

Comment: This is an example of an XY problem. You don't care about reading the output from the console; you care about getting this specific output in a log file. So, the actual question is: how do you get the Django development server to log to a file?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I've tried this but from what I've found and read if the server is in debug mode it will only give a blank log file.

Comment: Note that the current development version [has a change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/#runserver-output-goes-through-logging) which makes devserver output go through the logging module, so you can configure it to go wherever you like.